# React js handle error from request api Laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

Hello guys I have a problem to handle error from validation Laravel
i have service class

```
import axios from "axios";
import { LogIn } from "react-feather";
import Alert from "../components/Alert";
import { API_BASE_URL  , BASE_URL} from "../config";

class UserService {

   async getUserInformation(id){
       try{
        const result = await axios.get(API_BASE_URL + '/getUserInformation' , { params: { id: id } })
        return result.data.users
       }catch(e){
        return false;
       }
   }

   async saveUserInfromation(user){
       try{
        const result = await axios.put(API_BASE_URL + '/update' , user )
        return result.data.users
       }catch(e){
       
        return e.response.data;
       }
   }
}

export default new UserService();
```

and this is my component I call the function from class service to edit user

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Clientedit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user : {},
      oldPassword: "",
      newPassword: "",
      isLoading : true,
      error : "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }

   handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let user = this.state.user;
    try{
      const res = UserService.saveUserInfromation(user);
    
    }
    catch(e){
      
    }
  }
  }
}
export default withParams(Clientedit);
```

when I log error from service class I get it in my consol
[image]

but when I log it from my component I get nothing , any solution please

Answer (score 0):

You must set password_confirmation parameter when updating your password

Comment: The problem is not the error the submit work , just i want to display errors validation in my component when validation fails